# Typeof shows only exact result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a search filter for mine object. But he only shows exact result like:

Array data:

```
name => 'foo',
name => 'fa',
name => 'bar',
```

What i've is:

```
getObjects(array, 'name', 'foo');
```

If i search on 'f' i get nothing. when i search on 'foo' i get 'foo'. What i want is, if i search on 'f', i want 'foo' and 'fa'.

Code

```
function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] === 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i == key && obj[key] == val) {
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

I like to hear from you, thanks a lot!

Comment: please add an example. do you mean the key or the value to compare?

Comment: Don't know what you are trying to achieve, but by using "===" it will match only exactly typeof .. even 2==="2" will fail in condition check.

Comment: I've edit the question.

Comment: @PieterDijkstra: I think your code can be quite a bit simpler. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = 'blabla';
alert(a.includes('la'))

function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] === 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i.includes(key) && obj[key].includes(val)) {
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), or with ES6 [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] === 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i.indexOf(key) !== -1 && obj[key].indexOf(val) !== -1) {
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}

var array = [{ name: 'foo' }, { name: 'fa' }, { name: 'bar' }];
    
console.log(getObjects(array, 'name', 'f'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Isn't that `String#indexOf` / `String#includes`? (The OP's actual data is a little vague)

Comment: The second one give everything but not the right one. and the rest give me only when i search 'foo' i get 'foo' and when i search 'f' i didn't get 'foo' or everything else with 'f' in it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make this a *lot* simpler.

If I read the question correctly, this is your data:

```
var array = [{name: 'foo'},{name: 'fa'},{name: 'bar'}];
```

Then it's not that much work to get all the items where a specific key contains a specific value:

```js
var array = [{name: 'foo'},{name: 'fa'},{name: 'bar'}];

function getObjects(array, key, value) {
    return array.filter(function(item) { // I only want items that...
        return item[key] &&              // Have the current key
            item[key].includes(value);   // And it contains the value I'm looking for.
    });
}

console.log(getObjects(array, 'name', 'foo'));
console.log(getObjects(array, 'name', 'a'));
console.log(getObjects(array, 'name', 'f'));
console.log(getObjects(array, 'baz', 'woo')); // No results for bad key.
```

Note that you could use `item.hasOwnproperty(key) &&` instead of `item[key] &&`, if that's something you need to worry about.

Comment: thanks a lot man! But the return is not the key but the hole object filtert by the key.

Comment: @PieterDijkstra: I'm not sure what exactly you mean. The return value from my example isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: The return value is an array not item[key] but only item :D But for the rest your code is ok.

Comment: I stil don't get it. Can you give an example of the return value you'd expect?

Answer (score 0):

for

```
i == key && obj[key] == val
```

you can use

```
i.includes(key) && obj[key].includes(val)
```